# Import duplicate row data into a derived column

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, duplicates, etl

I have an excel table where we run samples in duplicate and I would like to import the results from the duplicate run into a derived column so that there would only be one row per sample in my destination table.

The data might look like this:

| ID | result | mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aa | 145 | 146 |
| Aa | 147 | 146 |

And I would like the destination to look like this

| ID | result1 | result2 | mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aa | 145 | 147 | 146 |

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: do you need a sql script?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is pivoting.

Comment: @ARAT That would work if I only had 2 rows but there're a number of rows with different samples each with a duplicate row.

Comment: then can you provide a minimal example and tell us whether you want to do this in Excel or SQL?

Comment: I'm using SSIS to import the data from multiple excel files and would like to know if there is a way to identify duplicate rows from the ID column, and then pivot only the result column into a new derived column for each unique ID. Preferably all of this would take place within the SSIS import package.

Comment: If Power Query is an option, you can do a GroupBy operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an intermediate SQL Table like below :

1. First Data flow to get data from Excel file to the intermediate
   table :

[image]

Second Data flow to PIVOT the duplicate rows :

[image]

This is your PIVOT query :

> ```
> CREATE TABLE StagingTable ([ID] varchar(20), Result float, Mean float)
> INSERT INTO StagingTable ([ID] , Result , Mean ) VALUES ('Aa',145,146)
> ,('Aa',147,146)
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS
> (
> SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [ID]) AS Rn FROM StagingTable
> )
> select 
>     ID,
>     MAX(case when RN = 1 then Result end) Result1,
>     MAX(case when RN = 2 then Result end) Result2,
>     Mean
> from CTE
> GROUP BY ID,Mean
> ```

> ```
> ID | Result1 | Result2 | Mean
> :- | ------: | ------: | ---:
> Aa |     145 |     147 |  146
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7839d607adbe97f4775f36ece3277ee9)*

Comment: this solution only work with a fixed number of columns

Answer (score 0):

I think I will just generate an import that redirects the duplicates to a second table and use a view to joint the tables and select the extra column from the duplicates table.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27382229/9517769